# get value from a hidden field in mvc view, value already set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.Hidden("cinDays")
```

From inspect element:

```
<input id="cinDays" name="cinDays" type="hidden" value="127">
```

The value from #cinDays I want to be a parameter for a .cs C# method. This method is called inside an @if statement in my view

Comment: access in what way?, if its just on client side you can use js to get value

Comment: i need the value to be processed furthermore inside the view.  i want the value to be a parameter of a method used inside the view

Comment: you will need to add some code example

Comment: Please post your entire attempt and how do you want to send the hidden value to your `Controller` method? Are you using `AJAX` to this or a regular form submit? What have you attempted till now?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `cinDays` is a part of view model so you can access to this property like this

```
...

<div>
      @if(someFunc(Model.cinDays)) {
       //some code
      }
</div>

...
```

Comment: No, cinDays is not part of view model